# Prove that $ℤ[i]^*= \{1,-1,i,-i\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that $ℤ[i]^*= \{1,-1,i,-i\}$.

$\{1,-1,i,-i\} ⊂ ℤ[i]^*$ is trivial. But I'm not sure about the other inclusion.

Let $(a+bi) \in ℤ[i]^*$. Then there exist $c,d \in ℤ$ such that $(a+bi)(c+di)=1$.
Then $ac+bci+adi-bd=1$. Then $bc-ad=0$ and $ac=1+bd$. What can I conclude from this ?

Comment: An important tool in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is that you have a norm. Apply norm, then we get that $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z\to|z|^2$ is multiplicative,

$1=|a+bi|^2|c+di|^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$

Since $(a^2+b^2)$ and $(c^2+d^2)$ are positive integers divisible by $1$ they are equal to $1$.

Now, either

1) $a=0$ and ($b=1$ or $b=-1$)

or

2) $b=0$ and ($a=1$ or $a=-1$)

This because $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are integers.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with your first sentence, but I do get the same result if I take the absolute value of both sides:
$1=|1|=|(a+bi)(c+di)|=|a+bi||c+di|$ And then square both sides I get $1=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$.

Comment: My first sentence simply means that I used the property that for $z$ and $z'$ complex numbers $|zz'|^2$=$|z|^2|z'|^2$

Comment: Aah, then that makes sense. Thanks for your clear answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the *norm*: $N \colon {\mathbb Z}[i] \to {\mathbb Z}$, $N(z) = z\bar z$. This preserves multiplication and maps 1 to 1, so it restricts to a group homomorphism $N \colon {\mathbb Z}[i]^* \to {\mathbb Z}^*$. It's always positive, so $N(z) = 1$ for all $z \in {\mathbb Z}[i]^*$.

Now $N(a + bi) = (a + bi)(a - bi) = a^2 + b^2$, which can only be $1$ if $a = 0$ and $b = \pm 1$ or the other way around.

Comment: How do you $N(Z[i]^*) ⊂ Z^*$ ?

Comment: @90intuition For $u, v \in {\mathbb Z}[i]$, if $uv = 1$, then $N(u) N(v) = N(uv) = N(1) = 1$, so $N(u), N(v) \in {\mathbb Z}^*$.